# KineticJS not working in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

My program works perfectly in Chrome, but with FF and IE my canvasses are gone.
The error I got with Firefox is:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified:
...][c].apply(this[b],args)}})(c)}}(),function(){Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale=function...
On kineticJS.js (line 28) (KineticJS JavaScript Framework v4.4.0)
```

The error I got with IE is:

```
SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError 
h.addColorStop(g[i],g[i+1])
on kineticJS.js, line 28 character 7356
```

Does somebody know whats going on?

EDIT 3:

When I use `fill: 'white'` instead of

```
background = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          fillRadialGradientStartPoint: 0,
            fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 0,
            fillRadialGradientEndPoint: 0,
            fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 800,
            fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, '#262834', 1, '0f1114'],
          width: browserwidth,
          height: browserheight,
          name: 'background'
    });
```

That is placed in 'background' Rect that scales with the browserheight I got no erros in IE 10, 9 and FF.

But why is it happen only with fillRadialGradient and only in IE and FF? It has a connection with the error I mentioned before:

```
 h.addColorStop(g[i],g[i+1])
on kineticJS.js, line 28 character 7356
```

What it makes more strange is that I have another object with radialgradientfill which works fine in FF and IE.

```
var lichtrondje = new Kinetic.Circle({
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0,
                  radius: 90,
                  fillRadialGradientStartPoint: 0,
                  fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 0,
                  fillRadialGradientEndPoint: 0,
                  fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 90,
                  fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, '#DDD', 1, 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.0)'],
                  opacity: 1,
                  id: 'lichtrondje' + x,
                  name: 'lichtrondje'
            });
```

I have found out that the result looks different between the Chrome version and the FF and IE version. The right one is what its intended.

[image]

Comment: Need to see your misbehaving code to be able to help.

Comment: editted with new discoveries

Comment: please specify the browser version(s) you're tesing with (especially IE).

Comment: It causes the same errors in both IE 10 and IE 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are missing a # in the fillRadialGradientColorStops array

```
0f1114 --> #0f1114
```

Comment: Thanks! Chrome is less strict in it (making it more confusing)